# Convert any object to boolean in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am getting a dictionary as JSON response from server.From that dictionary there is a key **"error"** now i want to get the value of "error" key.I know that error always will be either **0** or **1**.So i tried to get it as boolean but it did not work for me.Please suggest how can i convert its value to boolean.

```
  let error=jsonResult.objectForKey("error")
  //this does not work for me
   if(!error)
  {
      //proceed ahead
   }
```

Comment: Cast `error ` to bool type

Comment: change this jsonResult.objectForKey("error").boolValue

Answer (score 4):

`Bool` does not contain an initializer that can convert `Int` to `Bool`. So, to convert `Int` into `Bool`, you can create an `extension`, i.e.

```
extension Bool
{
    init(_ intValue: Int)
    {
        switch intValue
        {
        case 0:
            self.init(false)
        default:
            self.init(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can get the value of key error using:

```
if let error = jsonResult["error"] as? Int, Bool(error)
{
// error is true
}
else
{
// error does not exist/ false.
}
```

Comment: You could replace that entire switch by `self = intValue == 0` :)

Answer (score 3):

**Very Simple Way:** [Updated Swift 5]

Create a function:

```
func getBoolFromAny(paramAny: Any)->Bool {
    let result = "\(paramAny)"
    return result == "1"
}
```

Use the function:

```
if let anyData = jsonResult["error"] {
    if getBoolFromAny(anyData) {
        // error is true
    } else {
        // error is false
    }
}
```

Also, if you want one line condition, then above function can be reduced like:

```
if let anyData = jsonResult["error"], getBoolFromAny(anyData) {
    // error is true
} else {
    // error is false
}
```

Comment: I kept the original answer because the question mentions that the return JSON contains 0 or 1 for that value. However, a more generic function would be an acceptable response:
```return paramAny as? Bool ?? false```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

Considering jsonResult as `NSDictionary` and error value is `Bool`. you can check it by following way.

```
guard let error = jsonResult.object(forKey: "error") as? Bool else{
    // error key does not exist / as boolean
    return
}

if !error {
    // not error
}
else {
    // error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that works much better. One thing I found was that in some dictionaries the Bool values comes in as Strings and need a String cast and check against "True".

Comment: key value depends on how json is built. we can set as string / bool / int.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is neither 0 or 1. It is an optional object. It is nil if there was no key "error" in your JSON, otherwise it's probably an NSNumber.

It is most likely that nil means "no error" and if it's not nil and contains a zero it means "no error" and if it's not nil and contains a one it means "error" and if it's not nil and contains anything else then something is badly wrong with your json.

Try this:

```
let errorObject = jsonResult ["error"]
if errorObject == nil or errorObject as? NSInteger == 0
```

When I say "try", I mean "try". You're the responsible developer here. Check if it works as wanted with a dictionary containing no error, with a dictionary containing an error 0 or 1, and a dictionary containing for example error = "This is bad".

Answer (score 0):

Check equality between `error` and `0` instead:

```
let error = jsonResult.objectForKey("error")

if error == 0 {
    // proceed
}
```

Comment: Who says? The compiler or you?

Comment: @deepakkumar If it's an integer to begin with, your original code should just work...

Answer (score 0):

Another Important point here is, you're using Swift and parsing the repsonse as NSDictionary. I can say that because you're using `objectForKey` method. Best practice would be to parse it as Swift `Dictionary`.

It may look like `Dictionary<String:AnyObject>` or `[String:AnyObject]`

Then you can check for the error as :

```
  if let error = jsonResult["error"] where error == 0 {
    //your code
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me

```
 if let error = jsonResult["error"] as? Int where Bool(error)
  {
            // error is true
           print("error is true")
  }
  else
  {
      // error does not exist/ false.
      print("error is false")
  }
```